# Touchpad + keyboard issues with Laptop Fujitsu Lifebook E5511 (same issue like Dell and HP, ....) ELAN „DesignWare“ tablet mode „i2c-hid-acpi“

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, laptop

Problem with all of them: Drivers get mental thinking its a TABLET ! The Laptop is no tablet ....

- keyboard not working
- touchpad not working

Applies to Ubuntu, Xubuntu, ...  18.x, 19.x, 20.x, 21.x, 22.04

THANKs to the may great, smart, encouraged, skilled people who invented all the details I collect and stuff together in the following as a solution proven to work in my machines - might their well being last forever.

Answer (score 0):

Problem & solution here:

1. keyboard
   wrong kernel module "elants_i2c" gets loaded. 
   There is no ELAN touchpad present.  
   This device has a „DesignWare“ Touchpad (which is not working, of course).  
   Stopping the wrong module helps to get the keyboard functional.  
   ONE way (not the only) is to disable the wrong module in grub:
   Change the existing parameter line in grub, update-grub, reboot 
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="initcall_blacklist=elants_i2c"
2. touchpad  
   The „DesignWare“ Touchpad does NOT need module „i2c-hid" like many others.  
   „DesignWare“ Touchpad needs module „i2c-hid-acpi“. 
   How to do that? 
   Hit-and-run solution: 
   Invoke  
   modprobe i2c-hid-acpi 
   and see if it works

ONE possible (persistent) solution of many is to create a systemd service.  
 Other suggestions welcome!  

a) create 
/usr/local/bin/touchpad-kmodule.sh
with +x for root 
content:
#!/bin/bash
modprobe i2c-hid-acpi

b) create 
/etc/systemd/system/touchpadELAN.service
access rights 644 for root 
content:  

[Unit]  
Description=load missing kernel module for touchpad  

[Service]  
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/touchpad-kmodule.sh  
Type=oneshot  
RemainAfterExit=yes  

[Install]  
# WantedBy=multi-user.target  
WantedBy=default.target

c) enable the serviced service  
sudo systemctl status touchpadELAN.service  
sudo systemctl enable touchpadELAN.service  
sudo systemctl start touchpadELAN.service  


Experience with some  similar machines / similar problems, other solutions; try this solution with your laptop to see if it helps   
X) f$#@ing "tablet" disable (where applicable / in many similar Laptops):  
Blacklist the wrong module this way 
Create a file   
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf

with content

# bug in module breaks keyboard, so do not load it (askubuntu.com 127820)  
blacklist intel_vbtn  




every one complaining about wrong formatting: do a better job first and then KISS MY FEET!